# Where can I see a different between cacheable="true" and "false" in layout?

Tags: magento2, block-cache, page-layouts

I know this is seem stupid question but I'm a newbie in Magento 2. So I want to ask you guys that **Where can I see a different between cacheable ='false' and cacheable='true'?**.

I checked in Local Storage in Chrome but it didn't show me anything different.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

Comment: @AnkitShah I know that document, but I need know where we can see the different between its.

Comment: `cacheable=false` on a block makes whole page not cacheable  or Pages containing such blocks are not cached.

Comment: Yes. Where we can check it has cached or not? I just need an evidence, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start at the `Magento\Framework\View\Layout::getOutput`.
As you may suspect, this transforms the layout to output.
In this method there is a call to `renderElement` from the same class.
This one renders each element of the page.
In this method, the event `core_layout_render_element` is dispatched.
And this event is observed by the PageCache module.

```
<event name="core_layout_render_element">
    <observer name="pagecache" instance="Magento\PageCache\Observer\ProcessLayoutRenderElement" />
</event>
```

Going to the `ProcessLayoutRenderElement::execute` method you should find this:  `if ($this->isFullPageCacheEnabled() && $layout->isCacheable()) {`

So if the full page cache is enabled and the layout is cachable some hole punching will happen in the generated HTML.

Now let's focus on `$layout->isCacheable()`.
The method looks like this:

```
public function isCacheable()
{
    $this->build();
    $cacheableXml = !(bool)count($this->getXml()->xpath('//' . Element::TYPE_BLOCK . '[@cacheable="false"]'));
    return $this->cacheable && $cacheableXml;
}
```

This means the page layout xml is generated and then Magento looks for a block element in the layout with `[@cacheable="false"]`. If there is at least one, then the page is not cacheable.

Comment: Great answer. And if you evaluate `$this->getXml()->xpath('//' . Element::TYPE_BLOCK . '[@cacheable="false"]')`, it will tell you which block is responsible.

Answer (score 1):

X-Magento-Cache-Debug: MISS shows that the page is never cached.
X-Magento-Cache-Debug: HIT this shows the page is cached.

These can be found in the headers of a request
refer : https://www.screencast.com/t/epI3jcPKA

Answer (score 0):

You will not see anything different in Local Storage of Chrome, Because in the current context, The block is cached on sever (if cacheable is set to **true**)

If you want to see the practical difference. leave a comment.

as per your comment, I am giving an example:

1) Go to Stores->configuration->customers->customer configuration->captcha

2) Enable it for login page, refer following settings

[image]

3) Enable the cache from admin / using CLI commands.

4) Now go to customer login page and refresh it 4-5 times and see the effect on captcha image.

5) Next open file customer_account_login.xml

6) edit the following code and remove cacheable="false"

```
<referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Captcha\Block\Captcha" name="captcha" after="-" cacheable="false">
                <action method="setFormId">
                    <argument name="formId" xsi:type="string">user_login</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="setImgWidth">
                    <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">230</argument>
                </action>
                <action method="setImgHeight">
                    <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">50</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

7) Now flush the cache and see the result after again refreshing multiple times. You will see the captcha is not getting changed properly.

Comment: Yes bro. I just want to see different between it. Can you help me?